# Reorder data frame columns whose names contain dates in date order?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a reactive data frame where column names change and the columns with `Month.Year` name are out of order. How can I put the first Month.Year to be the furthest left following "Current"? Below is how the data frame columns are ordered and how I would like them to be.

```
print(colnames(df))
#[1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "Report"             
#[5] "Apr.2019"            "Current"             "Feb.2019"            "Jun.2019"           
#[9] "Mar.2019"            "May.2019"            "Mar.2020"

#the order I want is below
#[1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "Report"             
#[5] "Current"             "Feb.2019"             "Mar.2019"            "Jun.2019"           
#[9] "Apr.2019"            "May.2019"             "Mar.2020"

#####################################################################
#another example of the df
print(colnames(df))

#[1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "Report"             
#[5] "Apr.2019"            "Current"             "Feb.2019"            "Jun.2019"           
#[9] "Mar.2019"            "May.2019"            "Sep.2019"

#the order I want is below
#[1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "Report"             
#[5] "Current"             "Feb.2019"             "Mar.2019"            "Apr.2019"           
#[9] "May.2019"            "Jun.2019"             "Sep.2019"
```

Here is some info for how the df looks

```
print(dput(droplevels(head(d3))))
#below is the output

structure(list(ProductCategoryDesc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CN AMMONIA", class = "factor"), RegionDesc = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST", class = "factor"), 
SourceDesc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CN-SD, WATERTOWN 
LIQUID", class = "factor"), 
Report = structure(1:6, .Label = c("InventoryAvailabletoShip", 
"NetCashPosition", "NetMarketPositionTotal", "NonDirectShipPurchase", 
"TotalDirectShips", "TotalNonDirectShips"), class = "factor"), 
Apr.2019 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Current = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), Feb.2019 = c(0, 0, 240, 240, 0, 240), Jun.2019 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Mar.2019 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), May.2019 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), sorted = c("ProductCategoryDesc", "RegionDesc", 
"SourceDesc", "Report"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = 
<pointer: 0x0000000000211ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
ProductCategoryDesc             RegionDesc              SourceDesc                   
Report Apr.2019
1:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID 
InventoryAvailabletoShip        0
2:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID          
NetCashPosition        0
3:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID   
NetMarketPositionTotal        0
4:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID    
NonDirectShipPurchase        0
5:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID         
TotalDirectShips        0
6:          CN AMMONIA AB REG 2 UPPER MIDWEST CN-SD, WATERTOWN LIQUID      
TotalNonDirectShips        0
Current Feb.2019 Jun.2019 Mar.2019 May.2019
1:       0        0        0        0        0
2:       0        0        0        0        0
3:       0      240        0        0        0
4:       0      240        0        0        0
5:       0        0        0        0        0
6:       0      240        0        0        0
```

Comment: It'd be really nice if you used `dput` instead of `str`. That way it would be copy/pasteable. Since you've got some factors `dput(droplevels(head(d3)))` should be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert to date whenever possible, and sort the columns :

```
x <- c("ProductCategoryDesc", "RegionDesc","SourceDesc","Report",             
 "Apr.2019","Current","Feb.2019", "Jun.2019",           
 "Mar.2019","May.2019","Mar.2020")

dates <-  as.Date(paste0("01.",x), "%d.%b.%Y")
x <- x[order(replace(dates, is.na(dates), "0000-01-01"))]
# [1] "ProductCategoryDesc" "RegionDesc"          "SourceDesc"          "Report"             
# [5] "Current"             "Feb.2019"            "Mar.2019"            "Apr.2019"           
# [9] "May.2019"            "Jun.2019"            "Mar.2020"
```

Your sorted data frame:

```
df[x]
```

Comment: I just fixed it, I meant "Current" first then followed by Month.Year from earliest to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy!

```
# Reorder columns in dataframe
df =
  df[
    c("ProductCategoryDesc",
      "RegionDesc", 
      "SourceDesc",
      "Report",
      "Current",
      "Feb.2019",
      "Mar.2019",
      "Jun.2019",
      "Apr.2019",
      "May.2019",
      "Mar.2020")]
```

To instead change the order of the dataframe by position aka index, try:

```
df = 
  df[c(
       1,
       3,
       2)]
```

If you are able to anticipate which index of the dataframe will be the most recent each time data is added to the dataframe, you could write the script such that it will take that dataframe and move it to the position you want. If for instance, it's the last column in the dataframe and you want to be begin moving it to the first position, you could try something like length(df) and use the length to indicate the very last element:

```
df = 
  df[c(
       length(df),
       1,
       3,
       2)]
```

Comment: That won't work since the dataframe is constantly changing length in the column names, that is why I showed 2 examples of df

Comment: Why is the dataframe constantly changing length in column names? Instead of using names to dictate the order, try using the index then instead.

Comment: It is a reactive dataframe within an R Shiny app

Comment: See my latest edits and hopefully they will help. If you can anticipate where the most recent data will appear each time your dataframe changes something like what I wrote should work. If it's always the second to the last column in the dataframe for some reason just try length(df)-1 and that should operate as an index for reordering purposes).